# Excel VBA QueryTables: Excel freezes in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA application that loops over 200 items. In every iteration there is this piece of code:

```
QueryQuote:
    With Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & strURL, Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = False
    End With

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                                            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                                                            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False
```

The source (URLs, variable strURL) is yahoo finance's API. In loop nr. 131 my excel simply freezes without error messages. Nothing happens. Are there any missing parameters I have to adjust?

Comment: In what way is loop 131 different from the previous ones.

Comment: It is just another url. I already tested this question. It is not this particular item 131. Maybe there is some queue which is limited?

Comment: Could also be that the website kicks you out as a DDOS protection. You might want to implement some sort of wait step inbetween loops.

Comment: I am sure this is not the case because I have the same application using a different method which for QueryTables works very well: 
[...]
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.Open "GET", strURL, False
http.Send
[...]